# Android creating and writing xml to file

Tags: java, android, xml, file, serialization

I'm taking a course on android app development and trying to create and write an xml file to the internal storage on the android.  I am having issues with how to set this up initially, as far as the methods.  I've written most of it but have errors that I can't figure out.  Maybe because I've been working on this all day, I don't know.   Here's my code for this class.  Errors I'm getting are illegal modifiers on public String treasures and FileOutputStream.   Any help would be appreciated.

Ok, I figured out the initial problem, needed to use try/catch.  Was able to run and everything worked fine until I got to the save file.  Getting an error now:

```
SoundPool error loading/system./media./audio./ui/KeypressReturn.ogg.  
AudioService Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturnj.ogg
```

This comes right after the "file created" is written to the log.  I'm guessing it's trying to write to the wrong file?  Need it to write to /data/data.  There is no audio in my app.  I've added the new code below:

***Old Code:***

```
    public void onSaveTreasureClick(View v) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Log.v("SaveTreasure","Button was clicked");
        File f = new File(getFilesDir(),"treasure.xml");
        FileOutputStream myFile=openFileOutput(f);
        Log.v("WriteFile","file created");  


        private FileOutputStream openFileOutput(File f) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }



    public String treasures(Treasure treasure) throws Exception{

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        StringWriter write = new StringWriter();
        final EditText tres=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.treasureNametxt);
        String treasureName=tres.getText().toString();
        final EditText c1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue1Txt);
        String clue1=c1.getText().toString();
        final EditText c2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue2Txt);
        String clue2=c2.getText().toString();
        final EditText c3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue3Txt);
        String clue3=c3.getText().toString();
        final EditText ans=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerTxt);
        String answer = ans.getText().toString();
        final EditText loc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationTxt);
        String location = loc.getText().toString();
        final EditText pv=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pointValueTxt);
        String pointValue=pv.getText().toString();

        xmlSerializer.setOutput(write);
    //start Document
        xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8",true);
    //open tag <items>
        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Items");
        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Treasures");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "TreasureName");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", TreasureName, treasureName);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "TreasureName");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Clue1");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "Clue1", clue1);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Clue1");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Clue2");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "Clue2", clue2);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Clue2");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Clue3");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "Clue3", clue3);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Clue3");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "answer");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "answer", answer);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("","answer");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "location");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "location", location);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "location");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Points");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "PointValue", pointValue);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Points");

        xmlSerializer.endTag("","Treasures");
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Items");

        xmlSerializer.endDocument();

        return treasure.toString();

    }

    }  

}
```

***New Code:***

```
public void onSaveTreasureClick(View v) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException{
        Log.v("SaveTreasure","Button was clicked");
        File f = new File(getFilesDir(),"treasure.xml");
        FileOutputStream myFile=openFileOutput(f);
        Log.v("WriteFile","file created");  


    //  private FileOutputStream openFileOutput(File f) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  return null;
    //  }


try{
    final String treasures;

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        final EditText tres=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.treasureNametxt);
        String treasureName=tres.getText().toString();
        final EditText c1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue1Txt);
        String clue1=c1.getText().toString();
        final EditText c2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue2Txt);
        String clue2=c2.getText().toString();
        final EditText c3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue3Txt);
        String clue3=c3.getText().toString();
        final EditText ans=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerTxt);
        String answer = ans.getText().toString();
        final EditText loc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationTxt);
        String location = loc.getText().toString();
        final EditText pv=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pointValueTxt);
        String pointValue=pv.getText().toString();

        xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
    //start Document
        xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8",true);
    //open tag <items>
        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Items");
        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Treasures");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "TreasureName");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", treasureName, treasureName);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "TreasureName");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Clue1");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "Clue1", clue1);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Clue1");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Clue2");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "Clue2", clue2);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Clue2");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Clue3");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "Clue3", clue3);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Clue3");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "answer");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "answer", answer);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("","answer");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "location");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "location", location);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "location");

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Points");
        xmlSerializer.attribute("", "PointValue", pointValue);
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Points");

        xmlSerializer.endTag("","Treasures");
        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Items");

        xmlSerializer.endDocument();

        writer.toString();
                myFile.write(writer.toString().getBytes());

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    throw new SAXException(e);

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}

}
```

Comment: I am a newbie...sorry I don't understand.

Comment: When you run code on the emulator or with your device attached to your computer, the Android Log will show a stack trace when the program crashes. It's a series of error logs that shows the chain of methods that led to an uncaught Exception.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have used that for other things.  This error is more syntax related and can't run it through the emulator until it's fixed. Error in code needs to be fixed first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this one out.  I was using the attribute tag incorrectly.  Come to find out, I didn't even need to use it.  The correct way was to do the following:

```
xmlSerializer.startTag("", "TreasureName");
xmlSerializer.text(treasureName);
xmlSerializer.endTag("","TreasureName");
```

After changing all of them, I was able to create the file and write the data to it.