# How to save a ListView into a xml file in Android?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am developing an android app capable of detecting BLE signals and list them in a ListView. After an Scan period of time it will stop scanning. Here is the code (it is the same as in the developers page):

ScanBleActivity.class (extends from ScanBaseActivty):

```
public class ScanBleActivity extends ScanBaseActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();


// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 20000;

  /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see com.zishao.bletest.ScanBaseActivity#initScanBluetooth()
  */
 protected void initScanBluetooth() {
   BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
   mBluetoothAdapter = manager.getAdapter();
   startScanLen(true);
  }

  @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mScanning) {
    startScanLen(false);
    }
}

  /**
  * 
  * @param enable
  */

  private void startScanLen(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
    new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            addDevice(device, rssi);

        }
    };
```

AddDevice is implemented in other class, in this case ScanBaseActivity:

ScanBaseActivity (which extends from ListActivity):

```
abstract public class ScanBaseActivity extends ListActivity {

protected LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices_scan);
mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter(this, new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>());
this.setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
initScanBluetooth();
}

 /**
 * Start Scan Bluetooth
 * 
 */
abstract protected void initScanBluetooth();

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) mLeDeviceListAdapter.getItem(position);
ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
String uuidString = "Getting UUID's from " + device.getName() + ";UUID:";
if (null != uuids && uuids.length > 0) {
    uuidString += uuids[0].getUuid().toString();
} else {
    uuidString += "empty";
}
Toast.makeText(this, uuidString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

  /**
  * @param device
  */

protected synchronized void addDevice(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device, rssi);
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
}
```

All the information I detect (name, address, rssi, etc) is listed in a Listview. For the ListView I have implemented an Adapter called BaseAdapter. Part of the code of the Adapter is the following:

```
public class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<BluetoothDevice> data;
private Activity context;
private final HashMap<BluetoothDevice, Integer> rssiMap = new HashMap<BluetoothDevice,   Integer>();



public LeDeviceListAdapter(Activity context, List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

public synchronized void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {
    if(!data.contains(device) ){
    data.add(device);
    }
    rssiMap.put(device, rssi);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.leaf_devices_list_item, null);
        convertView.setTag(new DeviceView(convertView));
    }
    DeviceView view = (DeviceView) convertView.getTag();
    view.init((BluetoothDevice) getItem(position), null);
    return convertView;
}

public class DeviceView {



    private TextView title;
    private TextView status;
    private TextView type;
    private TextView address;
    private TextView rssivalue;

    public DeviceView(View view) {
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
        status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_status_txt);
        type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_type_txt);
        address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address_txt);
        rssivalue = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.signal_intensity_txt);
    }
```

When the scan finishes I would like to save the ListView into a file (if it is possible into a xml file) but I don´t know where and what code I should use in the project to save it. It would be imortant also to use a timestamp in the file to know when it was saved. Can anyone help me or give me any clues??

New: Code Edited to show All code from ScanBaseActivity and ScanBleActivity!!!

Comment: what do you mean by "saving listview into a file" exactly?

Comment: My app shows a in a Listview BLE signals detected during the scan period (shows also more information). What I would like to do is to save all the items/information that has been shown into a file. It is more clear?

Comment: You do not "save the ListView into a file". You save the *model data* to a file.

Comment: What is the model data? Maybe I am a bit mistake of how to tell what I need. I need is to save the content of each item from the listview in  a file. Is better this way?

Comment: in your case you want to save "private List<BluetoothDevice> data" as it contains discovered devices.

Comment: But what I would like to save at least is the name, address and rssi of each item from the ListView after the scan period. How I do implement that part??

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem with your constructor.

```
    public LeDeviceListAdapter(Activity context, List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
    //EDIT::
    //add the following line
    super(context, R.layout.leaf_devices_list_item, data);

    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;

}
```

Calling the super constructor passes the reference of data to the BaseAdapter. Then, BaseAdapter will be able to handle any changes in the list.

Comment: When I put the line you have told me that is missing, the following error occurs: "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor". Without that line my app is working perfectly. But about my question of this thread, do you know how all the information of each item of the listview into a file??

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have edited my answer which will fix the error. As far as saving to file is concerned, I would suggest either using database or SharedPreferences.

Comment: It still gives me a problem: "The constructor BaseAdapter(Activity, int, List<BluetoothDevice>) is undefined". As I told you before, the app is working perfectly. I used another class to implement the BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make a couple of assumptions here, so correct me if I am wrong.
You have access to your Adapter from the class that is scanning for the devices. I assume this is how you are adding devices to the adapter using add device. You could make a call from here to the adapter when scanning completes to get the List of devices you have stored, by creating a public method on the Adapter which returns a BluetoothDevice List.
The second option you have is to just create the xml file you want in the adapter whenever you add a device to the list. There should not be many devices around, so you should have a fairly small number of read writes. Writing to an xml file should follow the procedure in this answer.
[Android creating and writing xml to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423650/android-creating-and-writing-xml-to-file)

(edit)
You would be looking at something like:

```
public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                //Add the call here to save the file
                // You should be able to access the list adapter from your base class
                // that will give you the devices 
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
```

Comment: You were very near but the addDevice is implemented in other class (in this case ScanBaseActivity) but is what you have told (I have modified the code to introduce the other class). I don´t understand very much what you are trying how to do it as you have told me. Where I should write the code for creating the file and saving the list? How I should write or which commands should I use? Sorry for the inconvinience but I haven´t worked yet with creating/writing and I am bit lost.

Comment: If it is possible I will need to do the first method which after finishing the scan, it saves the list. I should implement this in StartScanLen, in the run method, no¿?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in the run method of the postDelayed handler. This gets run when the scan period is completed and we are cancelling the scan. At this point in time, the adapter should have all the bluetooth  device details and we can get the list from it.

Comment: but the list it will be saved in ScanBaseActivity or in ScanBleActivity? Zomb, can you edit my code and show me how you would do it? I will modify the ScanBaseActivity and ScanBleActivity to show you all the code missing so that it is more clear.

Comment: I have added an edit to show you where the code goes. Make a public method on the ListAdapter to give you your devices. Then just use that data to write to file.

Comment: You mean to write the method in the ScanBaseActivity or in LeDeviceListActivity?

Comment: You can write the xml creator method in the ScanBleActivity.