# Send data from Android using REST XML (which library to use)

Tags: android, xml, rest

I have a link Where i want to send data in REST XML format, below is the sample xml that i must send. How make a xml structure like below and send it to the given link ? (Through Android application using JAVA)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE applicants PUBLIC "//National Informatics Center/" "../../files_uc09/llform.dtd">
<!-- Warning: Please Don't change the DTD declaration -->
<applicants>
<applicant refno="1">
    <licence-type>l</licence-type>
    <statecode>MH</statecode>
    <rtocode>MH02</rtocode>
    <applicant-name>
        <first-name>Bhairas</first-name>
        <middle-name>Rao</middle-name>
        <last-name>ray</last-name>
    </applicant-name>
    <gender type="male"/>
    <dob>1-07-1961</dob>
    <birth-place>Warangal</birth-place>
  ..
.(and so on its big )
.
</applicants>
```

So How to fill my data in this type of xml format and send it to some link.
Note: I cannot control any thing on server side. I can just send in prescribed format and receive response .

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423650/android-creating-and-writing-xml-to-file and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-androidxml/

Comment: Rest is for json why you want to use xml? Use Soap service if you want to use xml

Comment: Dear  Clairvoyant, as i already mentioned I cannot control server side . besides REST do Support XML, Json and both at same time as per documents given here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/

Comment: Dear Signare , thank you the IBM link looks promising .. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

-Using **these two class**:-

`DocumentBuilderFactory` and`TransformerFactory` you can post your data to server in xml format

Answer (score 1):

You can try amazing Retrofit library http://square.github.io/retrofit/. Check out "Content format Agnostic" section