# Generate xml by edittext and spinner values

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, spinner

I have many EditText and Spinners and i wan't to create a xml file after my validation button, but I don't know how to get values and put them in a xml variable.

I try to search a tutorial but i fnd nothing: https://www.google.fr/search?biw=1366&bih=608&noj=1&q=android+form+values+in+xml&oq=android+form+values+in+xml

```
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marge"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/marge"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/marge"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/marge">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/votreSituation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marge2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="1. Votre situation financière"
                    android:textColor="#2B729F"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/h1"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/projet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/votreSituation"
                    android:text="Votre projet*" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerProjet"
                    style="@style/spinner_style"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/projet"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:entries="@array/projet"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvProjet"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerProjet"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerProjet"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:paddingRight="50dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/creditsImmobiliers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerProjet"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marge"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marge2"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/marge"
                    android:text="Crédits immobiliers :"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/h2"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCredits"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/creditsImmobiliers"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/creditsImmobiliers"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:paddingRight="50dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mensualitesTotales"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/creditsImmobiliers"
                    android:text="Mensualités totales*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editMensualitesTotales"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/mensualitesTotales"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="#EBEBEB"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/capitauxRestants"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editMensualitesTotales"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marge"
                    android:text="Capitaux restants dûs*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editCapitauxRestants"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/capitauxRestants"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="#EBEBEB"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/creditsConsommations"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editCapitauxRestants"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marge"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marge2"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/marge"
                    android:text="Crédits consommations :"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/h2"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mensualitesTotalescc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/creditsConsommations"
                    android:text="Mensualités totales*" />

...

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/telephone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marge"
                    android:text="Téléphone*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTelephone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/telephone"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marge"
                    android:background="#EBEBEB"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="14"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/declare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editTelephone"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marge2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marge2"
                    android:text="Je déclare sur l'honneur l'exactitude des informations renseignées" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDeclare"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/declare"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/declare"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/valider"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/declare"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marge2"
                    android:background="#EC5256"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/marge"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/marge"
                    android:text="Valider"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Here my fragment:

```
    valider.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
```

... Check empty values
}
});

Comment: why do you want to create xml files?

Comment: @IljaKO I have to create a xml for use SOAP web service to send data

Comment: what about an xml parser

Comment: @IljaKO can i put values in a string variable instead of a xml file ? I want a string variale containing xml code

Comment: i bet you can : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562160/in-java-how-do-i-parse-xml-as-a-string-instead-of-a-file

Comment: @IljaKO So first i have o create a xml file, how to get edittext and spinner values and put them in a xml file after validation button ? I search on xml parser, i found: "XmlPullParser" its the solution ? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html

Comment: @IljaKO its ok i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423650/android-creating-and-writing-xml-to-file